# PHPUnit|Laravel phpunit running only the first test of class test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Currently, I am trying to run some simple unit tests with phpunit on a laravel project with the command line phpunit tests/Unit/ExampleTest. But it is only running the first method. Anyone has a solution ? Thank you !

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    /**
     * An other basic test
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function secondTestBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function basicTest(){
        $response = $this->action('GET', 'DepartementsController@display', ['id' => 1]);
        $view = $response->original;
        $this->assertEquals(1, $view['$dpt->iddepartement']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

PHPUnit by default launches only methods beginning with `test` prefix, so `secondTestBasicTest` and `basicTest` do not fall under that condition. You can explicitly annotate your tests as `@test` in PHPDoc to override this behavior:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function basicTest() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver !

Comment: Also, keep in mind your class name should be ended with the "Test" word.